# Creating Daemons in Linux... how should the file permissions be?

Tags: linux, php, file-permissions, daemon

I am setting up a few PHP Gearman Daemons running on PEAR System_Daemon. I need them to be able to write to the following locations...

```
/var/run/{APPNAME}.pid
/etc/init.d/{APPNAME}
/gearman/log/{APPNAME}.log
```

What permissions should I set for them? I don't mind creating a different user or what have you, but I am just not the greatest with File Permissions. I want to do this right, not chmod 777 for ease of use and running as root which is never a good idea.

Help this file permission idiot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a user:group for this daemon, and give them the permissions you need.

As root you can always

```
sudo -u newuser $program
```

Comment: What exact chmod should I give them? Obviously init.d will need the most, but I don't want to do a blanket chmod 777...

Comment: I'd say 550 should be ok. and of course `chown $user:$group script.sh`

Comment: chmod 550 = Read + Execute for Group and Owner Right?

...wouldn't the log file need to a write flag?

Comment: yes, if you're writing, you'll need to have rw access, 660 I guess

Comment: Yes, the System_Daemon method writes an init.d script on first or updated startup, updates log file always, and needs to write the PID file. I'll try this later today / tomorrow and let you know if System_Daemon likes the new settings. Much better than blanket permissions :)

Comment: I hope it works, just in case, I would give blanket permissions to the logging part of the script, so that if anything goes wrong, it can be logged.
After everything works, logs can be tightened as well

Comment: Seems to work, marking it as correct, need to use 660 and not 550 for readers that came here from google